# Order By multiple columns (Datetime and varchar)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query about a table that records conversations and stores the name, the chatid and the date and time of the conversation. My problem is that sometimes people write at the same time and the conversations are mixed, I have tried different ways to perform the query and I have not succeeded. I attach the query and an example of the returned query and the expected query, thanks!

```
SELECT  WhatsApp.username
      , WhatsApp.chatid
      , WhatsApp.fecha_reg
FROM wsappbotLog AS WhatsApp
ORDER BY WhatsApp.fecha_reg, WhatsApp.chatid
```

The result is as follows

```
| username |  chatid |       fecha_reg          |
| -------- | ------- |  ----------------------  |
|   Sara   |  57316  |  2022-08-25 08:15:29.053 |
|   Sara   |  57316  |  2022-08-25 08:23:51.280 |
|  Andrés  |  57320  |  2022-08-25 08:32:26.910 |
|  Andrés  |  57320  |  2022-08-25 08:32:41.587 |
|   Sara   |  57316  |  2022-08-25 08:33:24.813 |
|   Sara   |  57316  |  2022-08-25 08:35:06.670 |
|   Tom    |  57312  |  2022-08-25 08:35:46.960 |
|   Sara   |  57316  |  2022-08-25 08:36:39.000 |
|   Sara   |  57316  |  2022-08-25 08:36:52.160 |
|  James   |  57321  |  2022-08-25 08:38:39.670 |
|  James   |  57321  |  2022-08-25 08:39:14.797 |
|  James   |  57321  |  2022-08-25 08:39:15.187 |
```

And the expected result would be

```
| username |  chatid |       fecha_reg          |
| -------- | ------- |  ----------------------  |
|   Sara   |  57316  |  2022-08-25 08:15:29.053 |
|   Sara   |  57316  |  2022-08-25 08:23:51.280 |
|   Sara   |  57316  |  2022-08-25 08:33:24.813 |
|   Sara   |  57316  |  2022-08-25 08:35:06.670 |
|   Sara   |  57316  |  2022-08-25 08:36:39.000 |
|   Sara   |  57316  |  2022-08-25 08:36:52.160 |
|  Andrés  |  57320  |  2022-08-25 08:32:26.910 |
|  Andrés  |  57320  |  2022-08-25 08:32:41.587 |
|   Tom    |  57312  |  2022-08-25 08:35:46.960 |
|  James   |  57321  |  2022-08-25 08:38:39.670 |
|  James   |  57321  |  2022-08-25 08:39:14.797 |
|  James   |  57321  |  2022-08-25 08:39:15.187 |
```

Comment: Please show us the initial data used to generate those results.

Comment: I don't understand what the expected result is ordered by. It is not the date, it is not the chat id, it is not the username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work out the datetime of the first chat entry per user, `fecha_reg_min`, using the [`MIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/min-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). Then order by `fecha_reg_min` first (same as MatBailie said but without the CTE) followed by `chatid` since I assume you want to keep each chat together.

```
SELECT W.username
    , W.chatid
    , W.fecha_reg
    , MIN(W.fecha_reg) OVER (PARTITION BY W.chatid) fecha_reg_min
FROM wsappbotLog W
ORDER BY fecha_reg_min, W.chatid, W.fecha_reg;
```

Note the nice short table alias.

Comment: Dale, thank you very much for your answer, I don't have much experience in SQL and your answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Work out each chat's first datetime and order by that first.

```
WITH
  chat AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MIN(fecha_reg) OVER (PARTITION BY chatid) AS fecha_reg_min
  FROM
    wsappbotlog
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  chat
ORDER BY
  fecha_reg_min,
  chatid,
  fecha_reg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by the WINDOW function FIRST_VALUE it takes also care of of the correct sorting with the date and chatid, to get rid of the problem when two chats start at the same time. With more people this could happen, so I added a new sara2 to the pot, to show it sorts correctly

> ```
> SELECT
>     [username], [chatid], [fecha_reg]
> FROM wsappbotLog 
> ORDER BY FIRST_VALUE([fecha_reg]) OVER (PARTITION BY [chatid] ORDER BY [fecha_reg], [chatid])
> ```
>
> ```
> username | chatid | fecha_reg              
> :------- | :----- | :----------------------
> Sara     | 57316  | 2022-08-25 08:15:29.053
> Sara     | 57316  | 2022-08-25 08:23:51.280
> Sara     | 57316  | 2022-08-25 08:33:24.813
> Sara     | 57316  | 2022-08-25 08:35:06.670
> Sara     | 57316  | 2022-08-25 08:36:39.000
> Sara     | 57316  | 2022-08-25 08:36:52.160
> Sara2    | 57317  | 2022-08-25 08:15:29.053
> Andrés   | 57320  | 2022-08-25 08:32:26.910
> Andrés   | 57320  | 2022-08-25 08:32:41.587
> Tom      | 57312  | 2022-08-25 08:35:46.960
> James    | 57321  | 2022-08-25 08:38:39.670
> James    | 57321  | 2022-08-25 08:39:14.797
> James    | 57321  | 2022-08-25 08:39:15.187
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=70594ff9b70a00362377d9b85113c8be)*

Comment: That would put chat 57312 first, but the op wants it ordered later, which appears to be based on each chat's first entry.

Comment: @MatBailie i missed Ton, so i changed the query

Comment: @DaleK ye i didn't see tom

Comment: @DaleK that would be a problem, but it has a simple solution, to change the ORDER By in the Windown function

Comment: Still doesn't quite work. As there is only one expression in the Order By, this doesn't guarantee that each chat's rows are output in time order. To do that you need to add `, fecha_reg` to the outer query's Order By. Then, any two chats with the same 'start' will become interleaved. It has to be `start, chatid, fecha_reg` to fully guarantee the output required.

Comment: @MatBailie maybe you should give qan example where it doesn't work, or read up on window function, to get the values if an window function, the the selct process has to be finished, and then it sort the values after that what is written in the order by of the window function. so show us a fiddle where the code doesn#t work, and we can see for a solution. but it works

Comment: Relying on sorting data to fulfil both a window function and a required ordering is relying on an implicit side effect. It is Not a Guaranteed behaviour. I could write a dbfiddle to demonstrate that insert order of rows also affects output ordering, but it's still not Guaranteed. Relying on undocumented and unguaranteed side-effects is extremely bad practice, especially when there is a clean and explicit option to make the code intent more readable And reliable. Your answer Only guarantees that the output is sorted by the scalar value resulting from the window function.

Comment: I disagree, I can find no documentation supporting your assertion; it's not guaranteed to be deterministic.